# How to make a subquery get latest updates during UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have two tables, `organization` and `address`.

`organization` table has an `address_id` column but all the rows have `address_id` set to NULL.

I want to SET `address_id` in organization table equal to a random id in address table but I also want all the ids to be unique.

This is what I tried:

```sql
UPDATE organization
SET address_id = (SELECT id
                  FROM address
                  WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT address_id FROM organization WHERE address_id IS NOT NULL)
                  LIMIT 1)
```

But the subquery is not getting the updated values after each update.

What I'm expecting/trying to do:
Assuming on the first update sets `address_id` to 6, then on the next update 6 should not be returned since 1 organization already has the `address_id` 6.

But all rows in organization end up having the same `address_id`.
How can I go about this?

Comment: 1) This *... random id in address table but I also want all the ids to be unique* is not true. Basically you are selecting a non-null `id` from address. If it where truly random you could get duplicate `id`'s. 2) Are you running this in a transaction and not committing?  3) Define *... subquery is not getting the updated values  ...*. **Add information as text update to question**.

Comment: You can't do an update on a table where the updated data depends on the content of the table itself use as a filter. You will need to do so with a join and a better query to get the "random" address_id. Now, if it has to be random id, why you need it in the first place? I think you are not explaining the real purpose of what you are trying to achieve here. You are probably falling on https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I edited the question and added what I'm trying to do and what's actually happening

Comment: I don't think you think you understood the point. What you are requesting doesn't make sense. In a relational database related data should have a meaning. Updating a row in a table called `organization` with a random id that merely exists in the `address` table makes absolutely no sense, is the same as don't have it at all hence why are you trying to fill it with just existing random data? That's the question you didn't answer. What we are trying to state is that you might be approaching this in the wrong way. Is this some kind of exercise? Is it garbage data?

Comment: I don't see why the "why" is relevant. But yes it's an exercise and it's a bunch of garbage data

Comment: Thanks for explaining. The relevance of the why is to prevent one from giving a bad / incomplete / misleading answer that would not solve your problem and might even cause future ones. We don't know whether you were doing this for experiment or a production environment. If it was a production, we are merely trying to prevent you from creating a problem for yourself. As responsible developers we should make sure that when teaching something to someone we are doing so for the right reasons. Sorry if it bothered you.

Comment: @JorgeCampos very fair point, will keep that in mind when posting questions in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query assigns the next free address ID for each to each organization that does not have one, yet:

```sql
UPDATE organization
SET    address_id = a1.id
FROM  (
   SELECT a.id, row_number() OVER () AS link_id  -- arbitrary number (not strictly random)
   FROM   address a
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM organization o WHERE o.address_id = a.id)
   ) a1
JOIN (
   SELECT o.id, row_number() OVER () AS link_id  -- arbitrary number (not strictly random)
   FROM   organization o
   WHERE  address_id IS NULL
   ) o1 USING (link_id)
WHERE  o1.id = o.id;
```

Prepare the assignments in subqueries in the `FROM` clause to the `UPDATE`.
[Read the manual on `UPDATE` here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

Assuming no concurrent write access. Else you have to lock both tables to be sure.

If there are not enough free addresses, some organizations keep `address_id IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to achieve the results you desire you can use CTEs(Common Table Expressions) This will generate a list of available address IDs then update the organisation table

```
WITH available_address_ids AS (
  SELECT id
  FROM address
  WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT address_id FROM organization WHERE address_id IS NOT NULL)
)
UPDATE organization 
SET address_id = (
  SELECT id
  FROM available_address_ids
  ORDER BY random() -- This will select a random available address ID
  LIMIT 1
)
WHERE address_id IS NULL;
```

The common table expression(cte) available_address_ids will select all the address IDs that are not already assigned in the organization table.

Then the  update query will select a random available address ID from the CTE and assigns it to the address_id column in the organization table.

This will ensure that the organization table will contain unique and randomly assigned address id